# R combining dataframes / drop rows with conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames with the same columns that I
would like to combine. If any value in column "ID" of df1 and df2 is identical
I only want to keep the corresponding rows of df1 (there are no duplicate values in
this column in df1 or df2).
To give an example:

```
df1=data.frame(ID=c("id10", "id11", "id3", "id5", "id8", "id40", "id47", "id9"),
               Var1 = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep(NA, 2)),
               Var2 = c(rep("yes",4),rep("no", 4)))

df2=data.frame(ID=c("id3", "id4","id8", "id20", "id32"),
               Var1 = c(rep("A", 2), rep("B", 2), rep(NA, 1)),
               Var2 = c(rep("yes",4),rep("no", 1)))


>df1
  ID Var1 Var2
1 id10    A  yes
2 id11    A  yes
3  id3    A  yes
4  id5    B  yes
5  id8    B   no
6 id40    B   no
7 id47 <NA>   no
8  id9 <NA>   no

>df2
ID Var1 Var2
1  id3    A  yes
2  id4    A  yes
3  id8    B  yes
4 id20    B  yes
5 id32 <NA>   no
```

The output I am looking for:

```
> df_res
     ID Var1 Var2
1  id10    A  yes
2  id11    A  yes
3   id3    A  yes
4   id5    B  yes
5   id8    B   no
6  id40    B   no
7  id47 <NA>   no
8   id9 <NA>   no
9   id4    A  yes       #edited
10 id20    B  yes
11 id32 <NA>   no
```

So I kind of want to update df2 with df1. E.g. "id8" occurs in both dfs but df_res has only the one from df1 and discarded the entry from df2, while all unique id-values from both df2 and df1 are still present.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: In the expected output, there is no 'id4'.  Can you please explain why it is dropped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine `df1` and `df2` and keep only the rows with selected `ID`'s.

This can be done in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE)

#     ID Var1 Var2
#1  id10    A  yes
#2  id11    A  yes
#3   id3    A  yes
#4   id5    B  yes
#5   id8    B   no
#6  id40    B   no
#7  id47 <NA>   no
#8   id9 <NA>   no
#9   id4    A  yes
#10 id20    B  yes
#11 id32 <NA>   no
```

`data.table`

```
library(data.table)
unique(rbindlist(list(df1, df2)), by = 'ID')
```

and base R :

```
df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)
df3[!duplicated(df3$ID), ]
```

Comment: The first two solutions work with my data, thank you. The last one does not (I ended up with duplicated ids in df3 in my original data

Comment: You need to assign the changed data back for all the solutions `df4 <- df3[!duplicated(df3$ID), ]` and then check `df4`.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully `unique` + `rbind` could help

```
> unique(rbind(df1, df2))
     ID Var1 Var2
1  id10    A  yes
2  id11    A  yes
3   id3    A  yes
4   id5    B  yes
5   id8    B   no
6  id40    B   no
7  id47 <NA>   no
8   id9 <NA>   no
10  id4    A  yes
11  id8    B  yes
12 id20    B  yes
13 id32 <NA>   no
```

Answer (score 1):

If both the datasets have only one row per ID, an option is to bind them with `bind_rows`, do a group by 'ID' and `slice` the first row

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    slice(1)
```

---

Or another option in the current version (`> 1.0.0`) of `dplyr` is `rows_upsert`

```
rows_upsert(df1, df2, by = "ID")
```

Comment: The first solution worked for me, thank you! The second (rows_upsert) did not - it kept the wrong row for the duplicated ids (I used my original data not example data). If I changed to rows_upsert(df2, df1, by= "ID") I got a warning message and some of the variables linked to id turned NA in the output